# Check in via Lufthansa app

Tags: lufthansa, check-in, mobile-apps

Since I'd like to choose seats and avoid overbooking I'd like to check in in advance.

There is an app and they say that we can check in using it.

My questions are:

1. if I use app to check in should I print something else to show at the airport?
2. what to do when I arrive at the airport? Should I use my mobile to scan some code?

**Edit:** Since I'll not have access to a printer to print my boarding pass after checking in online (if I did), I'm thinking to use app. But I have to report my company about my flight so I need boarding pass.

3. Is it possible to export as pdf the boarding pass from the app and print it later?

**Edit 2:** from [here](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Mobile-Boarding-Pass-available-on-many-routes-worldwide) they say:

> Should you have any problems with your mobile boarding pass you can, of course, collect a conventional boarding pass from a check-in machine or from a Lufthansa check-in counter at the airport. The same applies if, for example, your mobile phone’s battery is flat or you have inadvertently deleted your mobile boarding pass.

4. Do you understand that we can check in using app and **also** print the boarding pass at the airport machines (a kind of second copy)?

Comment: @mts, so, I open app and show the code on my mobile to the scanner when I drop luggage and when boarding? Nice! But they will give some boarding pass with information? I need some document to prove that I got the flight to show to my company.

Comment: I've never done it but I'm not sure you get anything printed. Your company might accept a screenshot from your phone but why don't you just check-in at the airport and get your boarding pass there.

Comment: I want to be sure about the seats. It is possible to do this on Internet. Can I export the boarding pass from my mobile to print it after my trip?

Comment: If *"I'm not able to print my boarding pass if I use Internet to online check in. So I'm thinking to use app."*  is true, then this must be very new. I've done this many times, last in April, and it was never a problem. Just turn up at the  Check-In kiosk and start the process as if you had not checked in yet.

Comment: @DCTLib, sorry. Maybe I'm misunderstood.  I edited the post.

Comment: @Sigur I don't think that you've been misunderstood. As far as point 4 is concerned, you should be able to use the online check-in on the Lufthansa web page and then get a printed boarding pass from the check-in Kiosks at the airport. They do not charge for this service (at least in April they did not). There is no need to use an extra cell phone app and I would avoid using it, as this *may* make a difference (as users of the App tend not to print an additional boarding pass).

Comment: @DCTLib, thanks. I also don't like to use app. To be true I got my 1st smartphone 2 months ago. Well, I think that I will check in online and save the pdf to my memory card. Then I'll try to print the boarding pass at airport. If not, I guess that they can scan the code from my mobile even if I don't have the app. I can zoom the QR code on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

1. You don't need to print anything.  The App will automatically download a [mobile boarding pass](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Mobile-Boarding-Pass-available-on-many-routes-worldwide).
2. If you are checking bags, just go directly to the bag drop.  Otherwise, go directly to security and show the mobile boarding pass.  (If you have an iPhone, it will be in Passbook and already on your lock screen.)
3. Take a screenshot.
4. You can still print a paper one from the kiosk.  Also, if you check bags, they will usually print one for you at the bag drop (to attach the bag info stickers to).

Comment: Sorry for stupid question: how to do #3? I have Galaxy S4.

Comment: No idea.  Maybe there's an android.SE?

Answer (score 3):

For company reimbursement purposes, you can also print a [passenger receipt](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Passenger-Receipt), which is available online [up to 30 days after the flight](https://www.facebook.com/lufthansa/posts/10151494429909004).